# Problems compiling zephyr shield example

Tags: c, stm32, zephyr-rtos

I have an STM32 lorawan discovery board with an attached x_nucleo_iks02a1 shield. I'm trying to run the [microphone sample](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr), and I get an error at line 52

```c
const struct device *mic_dev = device_get_binding(DT_LABEL(DT_INST(0, st_mpxxdtyy)));
// identifier "DT_N_INST_0_st_mpxxdtyy_P_label" is undefined
```

I looked at the zephyr.dts file and noticed that there is no compat listed with the string st_mpxxdtyy so I suppose that is the reason for the failure. The board I am using is not a nucleo but does have the same arduino compatible headers. Do I need to port this shield to this board?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the overlay file *x_nucleo_iks02a1_mic.overlay* from */zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/shields/x_nucleo_iks02a1* to the root of your projectfolder.

Now you should be able to retrieve the device structure with:

```
const struct device *mic_dev = device_get_binding("MP34DT05");
```